# How to resolve key-binding conflict between Icicles and `super-save-mode`?

Tags: key-bindings, buffers, auto-save, icicles

I noticed that if Icicles is loaded then `super-save-mode` doesn't save a buffer when you switch to another buffer, though switching frames works.

Icicles seems so technically advanced, yet there is no bug tracker on the internet. All info sits on a wiki page. How/where can I report an Icicles problem?

I run Emacs 26.1

Answer (score 1):

1. **`M-x icicle-send-bug-report`** to send an Icicles bug report or feature request.

   And the doc, both on Emacs Wiki (page [Icicles - Debugging and Reporting Bugs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Debugging_and_Reporting_Bugs) and in file [`icicles-doc2.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-doc2.el), tells you this clearly:

   > You can report a problem you experience with Icicles at [IciclesIssuesOpen](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IciclesIssuesOpen) –- please follow the formatting suggestion provided there.
   >
   > But the best way to report an Icicles issue or pass along a suggestion is by email. Do one of the following:
   >
   > - Choose item `Send Bug Report` from menu-bar menu Icicles.
   > - Use `M-x icicle-send-bug-report`.
   > - Use `M-?` from the minibuffer. Then click button `Icicles Options and Faces` in buffer `*Help*`. Then click the link `Send Bug Report` in buffer `*Customize Group: icicles*`.
2. The question/problem is unclear.  You'll need to specify what
   `super-save-mode` is, and why you expect a buffer to be saved when you switch to another buffer.  That probably means explaining how `super-save-mode` invokes buffer saving when another buffer is switched to.

   For that, you'll need to provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce your problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file), or at least point to the code that `super-save-mode` uses or depends on to automatically initiate buffer saving.

   For example, *if `super-save-mode` simply advises* particular commands, such as `switch-to-buffer` then it will have no effect (by default) in Icicle mode -- see #3, below -- because (by default) `C-x b` in Icicle mode is not bound to command `switch-to-buffer`.
3. In Icicle mode, by default `C-x b`  is bound to `icicle-buffer`, and `C-x 4 b` is bound to `icicle-buffer-other-window`. But there's no requirement that anyone use those bindings. You can *customize option* **`icicle-top-level-key-bindings`** to remove them.